# How do I configure "Scan Multibranch Pipeline Triggers" in my jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Right now I manually configure my all my multibranch pipeline jobs and set "Scan Multibranch Pipeline Triggers" to 3 minutes.

How do I put this in my `Jenkinsfile`? I can't find examples of this. Is "Scan Multibranch Pipeline Triggers" available in the `triggers{}` block?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The settings on the multibranch configuration page only configure the multibranch scan job itself, not the individual jobs created inside the multibranch "folder".

The option under "Scan Multibranch Pipeline Triggers" that says "Periodically if not otherwise run" is only a trigger for when the multibranch job will scan for new branches. If changes are found to existing branches, or if new branches are discovered with a Jenkinsfile that match your branch specifications, a new build will be triggered, but this is not intended to be the way a job is triggered.

Actually, you can disable the automatic build when changes are found by adding a property to the SCM configuration to "Disable automatic SCM Triggering". Then then you will see the multibranch scan trigger, but the jobs themselves won't build, even if there are changes found.

To trigger jobs, ideally you should use a webhook if you can. If you use a git hook using the git plugin (not the github plugin), then you need to enable the PollSCM trigger (though you can set it to only poll rarely, or not at all).

If you just want normal triggering options, as of 2.22, you can configure the either `cron` or `pollSCM` triggers.

```
pipeline {
    triggers {
        cron('H/4 * * * 1-5')
        pollSCM('0 0 * * 0')
    }
```

Then I believe you can configure webhooks to inform your multibranch job when to do a scan. I haven't tried that. I just tell it to scan every hour or a couple times per day using the "Periodically if not otherwise run".

Note, the same thing applies for the build discarder and other things you configure in your multibranch job. In the web UI, you can only configure the multibranch job itself, not the individual jobs created from it. You have to use Pipeline to configure the jobs.

Comment: Does the pipeline cron trigger build every branch? Or does it just scan? Is it possible to set a cron to trigger only one branch (master)?

Comment: The right property name is **Suppress automatic SCM triggering**.

Comment: Is it possible to trigger branch re-indexing via API? I have GitHub WebHook point to Lambda (lambda in turn filters GitHub events and only triggers Jenkins if certain comment is received). However, Jenkins doesn't re-index as GitHub WebHook isnt pointing to Jenkins Server directly. Lambda can't trigger a build until the PR branch has been discovered. When I try to forward the POST request of "pull_request" event from GitHub WebHook to Jenkins via the Lambda I get a "incorrect signature" error. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @Rob Hales - If new branch is created and it matches filter for branch name (or branch name regex) will the build job be triggered or not in this case???
I have set up new Configuration - after that my new branch is NOT triggered. After that I re-SAVE the configuration (I think this is related to indexing)and after that my build for that new branch is triggered. After that for every new branch job is triggered which is good. But why it didn't trigger at the first place?thx

Answer (score 7):

If your're using the [JobDSL Jenkins plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin) for creating jobs, then you can add following lines to configure "Scan Multibranch Pipeline Triggers":

```
configure {
    it / 'triggers' << 'com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.PeriodicFolderTrigger'{
        spec '* * * * *'
        interval "60000"
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that JobDSL or Jenkinsfile DSL?

Comment: its JobDSL groovy

Comment: what is the meaning of that block ?

Comment: What is the meaning of "spec". The UI only has a single "interval" setting.

Answer (score 3):

Using the JobDSL Jenkins Plugin for multibranch pipeline job, the periodic folder trigger can be configured as given below. In this example, the maximum amount of time since the last indexing that is allowed to elapse before an indexing is triggered will be seven days.

```
multibranchPipelineJob('my-awesome-job') {
    triggers {
        periodicFolderTrigger {
            interval("7d")
        }
    }
}
```